# Paste copied text to Webview page

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I create a custom menu which can copy text to the clipboard, but how can I paste it back if focused text field inside the HTML page?

```
 private class CustomMenuItemClickListener implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.copy:
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
                            new ValueCallback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("webView", value);
                                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                }
                            });
                    break;
                case R.id.paste:
                    ClipData clipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
                    ClipData.Item item1 = clipData.getItemAt(0);
                    String text = item1.getText().toString();

                    //Paste, how to access the selected field in the page?

                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.activeElement.value`, this should get the focused text field

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){document.activeElement.value = '"+text+"'})()",
                            new ValueCallback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                                }
                            });
```